How to get teams to notify members in a channel from an email sent with an @
I have made a VBA script to take data and comply into a report that has to be sent to a teams channel and notify 2 of the members. Currently this report is added to teams manually. I got the vba to send the email to the channel and everything I have read says if you do an @name in the email, it should notify the members just like if you do an @name from with in the teams channel, but it doesn't. Is there anything else I can try? Is it maybe the system admin has the function turned off?
I tried doing @first last and @last, first as well as including them as recipients on the email(notifying them via email is not acceptable apparently).
